# How to close an opened Excel file using Selenium/java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While automating I'm required to click on Edit Excel, make the changes and again open it to see if the changes have been made.  When I click on edit excel, the excel opens. I do the changes inside the code.  How do I close the opened excel in selenium. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Geetha is ur excel sheet is part of your application or its present on a local driver which u open for edit plz confirm

Answer (score 1):

It looks like on clicking Edit Excel, excel file opens and need to close that one right? so here we are not opening the file by java code just like FileInputStream etc... so i think we can close directly from cmd... just like below

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "cmd /c taskkill /f /im excel.exe");
```

Thank You,
Murali